# Is there a Java open source implementation of R2RML?

Tags: rdf, jena, csv, r2rml

I want to generate RDF data from tabular data, in particular: CSV, TSV, spreadsheets (either Excel or OpenOffice) and, eventually, tables in RDBMS.

I am aware of the "RDB to RDF Mapping Language" (R2RML) (http://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/) current draft.

I use Apache Jena for processing, storing and querying RDF data and/or reading CSV or TSV files. I use Apache POI for reading Microsoft Excel spreadsheets and I am planning to use Apache ODF Toolkit for reading OpenOffice spreadsheets.

Is there a Java open source (preferably ASL) implementation of R2RML I can use?

Comment: Modern answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45476632/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-rdb2rdf-tools. In short, Ontop.

Answer (score 6):

[D2RQ](http://d2rq.org/) is the underling implementation behind the popular [D2R Server](http://d2rq.org/d2r-server). Open source (Apache) and written in Java, so I guess it's exactly what you need.

Comment: Does D2RQ implement R2RML?  I can't seem to find anything that says that it does, and while D2RQ's mapping language and R2RML are similar, they aren't the same, I believe.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor It appears that R2RML support (modulo a possible bug or two in the test suite) is supported in the development branch, as of 2012.  See [Implement R2RML #84](https://github.com/d2rq/d2rq/issues/84) D2RQ's GitHub issue tracker.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/rdb2rdf/wiki/Implementations) you can find a list of current R2RML implementations. Maybe the Clojure one might be interesting for you ;)

Answer (score 3):

Before your actual question, you introduced another related problem regarding spreadsheets transformation into RDF. For that I'd recommend you to take a look to [Google Refine (now: OpenRefine)](https://github.com/OpenRefine) and its [RDF extension](http://lab.linkeddata.deri.ie/2010/grefine-rdf-extension/). Maybe [this screencast](https://youtu.be/_3BmNcHW4Ew) regarding how it's [used in LMF](https://bitbucket.org/srfgkmt/lmf/wiki/Google-Refine-Extension) would help you.