# SQL query/table to RDF

Tags: php, rdf, sparql, semantic-web, n-triples

Does anyone know of a tool/project which can convert SQL data to RDF triples?

There is a document here which states how to do it http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-rdb-direct-mapping-20110324/, but I was hoping there would be some PHP (or other) implementations of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656998/is-there-a-java-open-source-implementation-of-r2rml); here is a brief summary:

- there is a [page](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/rdb2rdf/wiki/Implementations) and a [report](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-rdb2rdf-implementations-20120814/) which maintain a list of projects that implements R2RML. (follow the links in my answer to open them)
- don't forget to google for R2RML + implmentation or your favorite programming language
- a useful and interesting tool to explore could be [Google Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/)