# Convert SQL database to RDF in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, rdf, semantic-web

**Hi there**

I'm new to semantic web and I have a project about that.

To be simple, I will receive data from a web form stored in an SQL database, and I will need to transform it to RDF to be able to send it again to another program.

I've been looking how to do that easily, with a generator or something similar but I only found [these recommendations](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdb-direct-mapping/).

I [this is a way to do what I want in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656998/is-there-a-java-open-source-implementation-of-r2rml), but I'd like to do it in JavaScript it would be way much easier for me.

I've also found some posts talking about the [software virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com), but all these posts are pretty old (5-7 years) and I can't find proper documentation / tutorials.

So my questions are :
 - Is there any easy way to do what I want to do ? (even if it's not in JS)
 - Do you have any tutorials than I can follow and that is up-to-date ?

If anything isn't clear enough or if you want more precision feel free to ask questions, thanks in advance.

Comment: there are plenty of RDB 2 RDF tools and approaches. clearly, you have to define a mapping in any case.

Answer (score 2):

In regards to Virtuoso and transforming entity relationship types (relations) represented as tables to relations represented as RDF sentence collections (or graphs), here are links to posts that walk you through theory and practice:

1. [Conceptual Relational Data Virtualization, using Existing Open Standards](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/conceptual-data-virtualization-for-sql-and-rdf-using-open-standards-24520925c7ce)
2. [Generate Relational Tables to RDF Relational Graphs mappings](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/generate-relational-tables-to-rdf-relational-graphs-mappings-using-virtuosos-rdb2rdf-wizard-c4b83402599a) — using Virtuoso’s RDF Views Wizard
3. [Customizing Virtuoso R2RML Scripts](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/customizing-r2rml-scripts-in-virtuoso-d57973d8fab) — e.g., tweaking for
   incorporation of terms from 3rd party ontologies